# Clang/LLVM Build Statistics Tools

Tags: objective-c, clang, llvm

My current project has clean build times that are ~30 minutes on a 3GHz 8-core Mac Pro with 32 gigs of ram. The project has around 14k files.

I have a few theories about root causes, one of which is a pch that is to large, but I was wondering if there are any tools built in to clang or llvm that would let me know what clang is spending those 30 minutes doing (linking, preprocessing, compiling, copying the pch etc).